# Electron-forge package generates an empty out folder

Tags: electron

I am working on app with electron and electron-forge, this app is being built on a virtual machine with no internet connection, so I got electron binaries files, and set the electron_config_cache to the path where I located the new binaries as well as for cacheRoot for packagerConfig in the package.json file, the problem is that:

When I run yarn package (electron-forge package) I am getting Done with green check next to each step which had been called by yarn package .. but the out folder is empty, while it should has appName-win32-x64 folder which contains .exe.

so does anyone have an idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a virtual machine problem, nothing related to electron forge itself, the VM was not able to copy the content from the temp folder to the out folder, this can be solved by changing the temp folder

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your package.json has the correct settings, including the "main" attribute as well as build directories. It seems electron forge uses electron-packager as its packaging platform so:

Following these instructions:

From [Electron forge](https://www.electronforge.io/configuration),[Electron forge - packager options](https://www.electronforge.io/configuration#packager-config), [Electron-packager options](https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/interfaces/electronpackager.options.html#dir)

Without a forge.config.js file:

Add this to your package.json:

```
"config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {dir:"./path/to/your/dir"},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip"
        }
      ]
 }
```

Or with a forge.config.js file:

In your package.json, make sure to have:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "config": {
    "forge": "./forge.config.js"
  }
}
```

In your forge.config.js:

```
{
  packagerConfig: {dir:"./path/to/your/dir"},
  electronRebuildConfig: { ... },
  makers: [ ... ],
  publishers: [ ... ],
  plugins: [ ... ],
  hooks: { ... },
  buildIdentifier: 'my-build'
}
```

I think it is most probable that forge is just not pointed to the correct dir, add the dir setting shown above.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I am using package.json .. but regarding the dir: "path-to-your-dir" , you mean the path to the electron application ?

Comment: also it is mentioned that:
Please note that you can not override the dir, arch, platform,outor electronVersion options as they are set by Electron Forge internally
https://www.electronforge.io/configuration

Comment: Shoot, I see what you mean, it's one of the reasons I prefer creating a template from scratch and using electron-builder. But I know that is not feasable when running from an existing app/template, I found this under their CLI section:
[Electron forge CLI]https://www.electronforge.io/cli#package
they use the '--app-path' flag to select the directory which defaults to '.', can you maybe use this flag in the packaging?

Comment: The alternative is to see if you can maybe use the makers option to use a different/seperate builder?